# 'this' becomes undefined in method after apply decorator

Tags: typescript, decorator

Context: I want to build a decorator to run an interceptor to format a return value.

Problem: 'this' becomes undefined after I applied the decorator.

```
// decorator
function UseAfter(this: any,  fn: (...args: any) => any){
    return (target: any, key: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
        const originalMethod = descriptor.value

        descriptor.value = (...innerArgs:any) => {
            let result = originalMethod.apply(this, innerArgs)

            return fn(result)
        }
    }
}

const middleware = (arg1: any) => {
    return {
        data: JSON.stringify(arg1)
    }
}

class Test {

    otherInstanceMethod() {
        console.log('accessing instance method')    
    }

    @UseAfter(middleware)
    method1() {
        console.log(this) // < --- undefined
        this.otherInstanceMethod()
        return 'ok'
    }
}

const test = new Test()
test.method1()
```

Comment: It should be `descriptor.value = function (...innerArgs:any) {`. `UseAfter` is not getting any `this` context set explicitly, it's a function that is invoked as-is.

Comment: you're right, the arrow function fcked up the this context, its working now, thank

Comment: @zerkms thanks, this was the trick that worked. Finally able to solve my caching decorator :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sake of completeness.

We should not use arrow function for descriptor if we want to preserve the context of `this`.

```
// decorator
function UseAfter(this: any,  fn: (...args: any) => any){
    return (target: any, key: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
        const originalMethod = descriptor.value

        // this should not be a arrow function
        descriptor.value = function (...innerArgs:any) { 
            let result = originalMethod.apply(this, innerArgs)

            return fn(result)
        }
    }
}

const middleware = (arg1: any) => {
    return {
        data: JSON.stringify(arg1)
    }
}

class Test {
    otherInstanceMethod() {
        console.log('accessing instance method')    
    }

    @UseAfter(middleware)
    method1() {
        console.log(this)
        this.otherInstanceMethod()
        return 'ok'
    }
}

const test = new Test()
test.method1()
```

This would output -

```
Test {}
accessing instance method
```